# is actionscript eclipse plugin still maintained?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3

Seems it's in beta since 2007:
http://www.asdt.org/

any free actionscript eclipse plugin that is uptodate and free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase you want a free IDE, then you can ask Adobe for a free educational version, with which you will get a licensed SDK and IDE for free , but only for educational version.

Details @ http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/

Comment: or a working professional who is freelancing.They have options for both.

Comment: well I don't see that and it takes weeks to receive answer but thanks :(